# Using buttons in a DataGridColumn, WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I'm converting a Winforms app to WPF and run in to this error. In the winforms application the system loads buttons into a datagridview. As theres no datagridview in wpf, I've used datagrid. Sadly though, the things dont work. For some odd reason i cannot fix, i cant test what i thought of, i get a weird displayindex error. What i was wondering if someone can tell me either an alternative to what is used in the winforms app or tell me if what i have written works.

Winforms Code:

```
Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    dgBoorMachine.Columns.Add(btn)
    btn.HeaderText = "del"
    btn.Text = "X"
    btn.Name = "del"
    btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
    dgBoorMachine.Columns("del").Width = 30
```

WPF Code:

```
 <Grid ShowGridLines="True">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="560"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="425" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="560" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="156" />
        <RowDefinition Height="55.2" />
        <RowDefinition Height="89.6"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="332.8"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="217.6"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dgSlijpMachine" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="X" Click="btn1_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: "i get a weird displayindex error" - you can't get it from xaml. fix your btn1_Click method, most likely

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because you're missing the <DataGrid.Colums> tag

instead of

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgSlijpMachine" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="X" Click="btn1_Click"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

it should be

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgSlijpMachine" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="X" Click="btn1_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now I don't know exactly what you want to achieve. What this will do, is add a column with a button to every row you add to your DataGrid and nothing else. If you actually want to populate your DataGrid with values, you should bind to the DataGrid's ItemsSource, eg.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgSlijpMachine" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
```

where MyItems is an ObservableCollection or similar type.